# Separate Directories from Files with "----" Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to separate directories from files in a list. I would like them to appear as follows:

1. DirectoryName1
2. DirectoryNameA
3. DirectoryName_Two

   --
4. FileName1
5. FileNameA
6. FileName_Two

Basically, I want two or three dashes in between my directories and files.
Here is what the following code looks like.

1. DirectoryName1
2. DirectoryNameA
3. DirectoryName_Two
4. FileName1
5. FileNameA
6. FileName_Two

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if  [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
   cd "$1" 2> /dev/null
   if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then
      echo "Please enter a valid directory."
   else
      ls -a | sort -k 1 | awk '{printf "(%d) %s\n", NR, $0;}'
   fi
else
   ls -a | sort -k 1| awk '{printf "(%d) %s\n", NR, $0;}'
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
    dir_to_list=$1
    if [[ ! -d ${dir_to_list} ]]; then
        echo "Please enter a valid directory."
        exit
    fi
else
    dir_to_list="."
fi

files=`ls --group-directories-first $dir_to_list`
DIRS="TRUE"

i=0

for f in ${files}; do
    if [[ ${DIRS} == "TRUE" && ! -d ${dir_to_list}/${f} ]]; then
        # First non-directory entry
        echo ----
        DIRS="FALSE"
    fi
    (( i++ ))
    echo ${i}. ${f}
done
```

Cheers

*Update: fixed bug for listing other directories*

Comment: That's it! I appreciate this so much!

Comment: I just noticed a bug when you try this on a different directory, so please use the version I just edited.